# Create Azure Red hat template with custom LVM partitions

Tags: linux, azure, redhat, lvm, packer

I want to prepare Azure template for Red Hat 8 servers with packer and I'm facing problem with setting custom LVM partitions.
For example, I want separate /var/tmp, /var/log etc.
I deployed some VMs based on marketplace image and they have default partition layout.

I thought about using cloud-init, but there is no information about LVM in documentation.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.